# Selecting text with keyboard.send_keys from within an autokey script?

Tags: autokey

Rather than selecting text and then triggering the script, I'd like my script to select the text. I thought I could select text with keyboard navigation (e.g., `"<shift>+<ctrl>+<left>"` to select the word to the left of the cursor. I can do that and the word appears to be getting highlighted in gedit, but if I follow that with `clipboard.get_selection()`, I get an exception that no text is selected.

```py
# Select the word to the left of the cursor:
keyboard.send_keys("<shift>+<ctrl>+<left>")

# Try to get the current selection (fails with "No text found in X selection"):
try:
    name = clipboard.get_selection()
except BaseException as err:
    dialog.info_dialog('error', 'autokey script exception: {0}'.format(err))
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is what I'm trying to do not possible with autokey?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. What it probably needs is a time.sleep(0.1) or similar before the clipboard API call. AutoKey runs at machine speed and many applications can't keep up. It's a good idea to surround any clipboard API calls with moderately long delays. You can always shorten or remove them after things work. If that doesn't fix it run a trace and post it on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey).